# Find the length of the diagonal of a trapezium

Tags: linear-algebra

Is there any way to calculate the diagonal ε of a trapezium with side lengths A,B,C and D, so ε creates two triangles with sides ABε and CDε, if A and C are parallel?

[Helpful diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tOWLB.png)

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that the angle between $a$ and $\epsilon$ is equal to the angle between $\epsilon$ and $c$.

Using cosine formula

\begin{align*}
\frac{a^2+\epsilon^2-b^2}{2a\epsilon}&=\frac{c^2+\epsilon^2-d^2}{2c\epsilon}\\
c(a^2-b^2)+c\epsilon^2&=a(c^2-d^2)+a\epsilon^2\\
\epsilon&=\sqrt{\frac{a(c^2-d^2)-c(a^2-b^2)}{c-a}}
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

No. Imagine the lengths are all the same so it is a square, then you can still skew it and change the diagonal length. The shape is not fully defined and you need more information.

Comment: It's a parallelogram, so sides A and C are parallel, therefore the diagonal length is constant

Comment: You should build a a square linkage out of those Legos with holes and those connectors. The diagonal definitely does change and the sides stay parallel. My answer is wrong though because you can't move a trapezeium with only one pair of parallel sides without changing the slope of one of the sides. But the accepted answer does break down in the case of a square.

Comment: I'm struggling to visualise this - how can the diagonal change, but the sides stay the same length and A and C are still parallel?

Comment: If you have a diamond and then you squish it you get a narrower and longer diamond. The top and bottom angles are equal, and the left and right angles are equal. Using this you can prove all the sides are parallel. Or you can just look at an image of a diamond and turn it.